# pymssql Error: The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, pymssql

I have the following Python script which is doing pretty well at extracting data from SQL Server via a Stored Procedure that is inputted to it:

```
import pymssql
import openpyxl
import os
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

filename = "Finance_Sales"
extension = ".xlsx"
current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
full_filename = filename + "_" + current_datetime + "" + extension

os.chdir("S:\\Python\\Finance\\Projects")

# Establish a connection to the database
conn = pymssql.connect(server = 'Accounting_XPL', database = 'R')
cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)

# Create a cursor
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Execute your stored procedure
cursor.callproc('[Outputs].[Fiance_Sales_Extended_sp]')

# Get column names from the description attribute of the cursor object

column_names = []
column_names = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]

print(type(column_names))
print(column_names)

# Convert the list in a DataFrame row
column_names_as_rows = pd.DataFrame(column_names).T

rows =[]
for row in cursor:
    rows.append(row)

#Iterate through result sets
while cursor.nextset():
    pass

print("Done")

df_r = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df_h = pd.DataFrame(column_names_as_rows)

# Concatenate the header and the result set
frames = [df_h, df_r]
df_s = pd.concat(frames)

#print(df_r)

df_s.to_excel(full_filename, index=False, header=False)

# Close the cursor and connection
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

However, the issues seems to be that for certain Stored Procedures I get the following error:

> pymssql._mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (7314, b'The OLE DB provider
> "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "Sales" does not contain the table
> ""Melvis"."Finance"."Pre_2023_sales_v"". The table either does
> not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that
> table.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server
> error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n')

I think inside this particular SP (I don't have access to it) has a reference to the view "Pre_2023_sales_v" on the linked server "Sales" which links to "Melvis.Finance.Pre_2023_sales_v". I checked that the view does indeed exists so it must then be a permission issue.

I'm not sure whether it's the case that using Windows Authentication in the Python script is causing the issue.

I am able to query the "Pre_2023_sales_v" view on the linked server using SSMS via Windows Authentication.

Thanks

Comment: There shouldn't really be any difference if you connect to same servers using same credentials, regardless if it's through python or ssms, unless there's something crazy going on. Perhaps some procedure creates this view, and you're calling things in the wrong order?

Comment: Hi @siggemannen. So I used pymssql to directly query the view in the linked server that it was complaining about: "cursor.execute('Melvis.Finance.Pre_2023_sales_v'). It worked sometimes and sometimes not. When it didn't work I got the error "The SCHEMA LOCK permission was denied on the object". Refreshing the linked tables and views list in Management Studio and running the Python script again seems to fix the issue. I'm wondering whether sometimes the linked server tables and views are not always up to date hence the missing view/table error? I've definitely ruled out the permissions issue